# How to remove the new-line characters from const char * type string

Tags: c++, string

I want to remove the new line characters from a string.

So far I am only able to find remove() function but I think begin() and end() is not supporting const char * type of string.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    const char *a = "\n remove all \n the new line characters \n";
    cout << a << "\n";
    remove(a.begin(),a.end(),"\n");
    cout << a;
}
```

Error-

```
ctest.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
ctest.cpp:9:11: error: request for member ‘begin’ in ‘a’, which is of non-class type ‘const char*’
  remove(a.begin(),a.end(),"\n");
           ^
ctest.cpp:9:21: error: request for member ‘end’ in ‘a’, which is of non-class type ‘const char*’
  remove(a.begin(),a.end(),"\n");
```

I also found the remove_if function on internet but it only support "isspace", "isdigit" type of filters. There was no "isnewline" and direct "\n" was throwing errors. I also found some traditional solutions which basically puts a loop on the whole string but I am avoiding those raw solutions as I am very new to this language.

Comment: The data of `a` is `const`, so it cannot be modified. You can make an `std::string` and then use `std::copy_if` with `std::back_inserter`.

Comment: @nwp, can you please provide sample for how can i remove new-line using copy_if. I changed "a" as std::string a ("\n remove all \n the new line characters \n");

Comment: The constness of literals aside... A plain pointer doesn't have any member functions.

Comment: If you have an `std::string` you don't need to copy anymore because an `std::string` can be modified. You still have the problem that you want `std::remove` to remove characters, but you gave it a string instead. After you fix that it should compile but produce incorrect output because `std::remove` doesn't actually remove the characters you don't want, it just moves them to the back, so you end up with some garbage at the end. But it returns an iterator to the new end of the string, so you can shorten the string based on that to remove the garbage at the end.

Comment: You can look up the "erase remove idiom" to solve the problem with the garbage at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make `a` writable by placing it into an array, because you cannot modify the content of `const char*`. Then use `std::begin` and `std::end` non-member functions to obtain the two ends of the sequence:

```
char a[] = "\n remove all \n the new line characters \n";
cout << a << "\n";
remove(std::begin(a), std::end(a), '\n');
cout << a;
```

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/cQNB9r)

**Note:** It goes without saying that a better way of doing it in C++ would be using `std::string`.

Comment: But now the type of `a` is no longer `const char*`.

Comment: @Jodocus: Your requirement doesn't make sense if it has to remain a `const char*` because the `const` is there for a reason.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight It is throwing "error: ‘begin’ is not a member of ‘std’. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: @Jodocus I don't think OP insists on the type to be `const char *`. He put it in the title because that's the compile error, but the first sentence says he wants to remove `'\n'`s from a string.

Comment: @some_guy [`std::begin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) is available in C++11 and newer. You need to use a switch on your C++ compiler to tell it to use C++11.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, that actually worked(g++ -std=c++11 ctest.cpp -o ctest && ./ctest). But is there any way to do it in standard g++?

Comment: @some_guy That *is* standard C++. C++11 specifically which is an international ISO standard. You can also use C++14 or C++17 instead to get some improvements, but they don't really matter for you yet. C++11 though does matter even for simple code.

Comment: @some_guy: You copied from the wrong places in the internet. Use `std::string` if you need a string.

Comment: Today you learned a valuable lesson about copying things from the internet.